# group by extract(year/month) doesn't work

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table "pu_sum_ebenen" with some daily values ("ebene...") in some categories ("va", "Detail", "Detail1").
Now i want to sum those values per month, but the SQL gives me still one line per day (of course without showing the date, but 31 lines per month within one category).

```
select
  extract(year from datum) jahr,
  extract(month from datum) monat,
  va,
  detail,
  detail1,
  sum(ebene1) ebene1,
  sum(ebene2) ebene2,
  sum(ebene3) ebene3,
  sum(ebene4) ebene4
from pu_sum_ebenen
group by
  extract(year from datum),
  extract(month from datum),
  va,
  detail,
  detail1;
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try `GROUP BY TRUNC(datum, 'MM')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

work-around: add a dummy-column, just to omit it in the select, see 2nd line in from-clause:

```
select
  extract(year from datum) jahr,
  extract(month from datum) monat,
  va,
  detail,
  detail1,
  sum(ebene1) ebene1,
  sum(ebene2) ebene2,
  sum(ebene3) ebene3,
  sum(ebene4) ebene4
from pu_sum_ebenen,
  (select 0 x from dual) dummy
group by
  extract(year from datum),
  extract(month from datum),
  va,
  detail,
  detail1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `va`, `detail` and `detail1` columns from `group by` expression and apply aggregation functions for all of them in the select list as in the following one :

```
    with pu_sum_ebenen as
    (
     select date'2019-01-31' - level + 1 datum,
            2*level as va,
            (31 - level) as detail,
            (90 - 2*level) detail1,
            (100- level) as ebene1 
       from dual
    connect by level <= 31   
    )
    select
      extract(year from datum) jahr,
      extract(month from datum) monat,
      sum(va),
      max(detail),
      avg(detail1),
      sum(ebene1) ebene1
    from pu_sum_ebenen
    group by
      extract(year from datum),
      extract(month from datum);

    JAHR    MONAT   SUM(VA) MAX(DETAIL) AVG(DETAIL1)    EBENE1
    2019        1     306       30          72           1547
    2018       12     686       13          41           1057
```

which returns rows only for months.

Comment: Thanks, i also saw, that omitting just one of the categories (va, Detail, detail1) in the select gives one row per month, but i still need the sums in all categories ...